# kuma disable envoy health check

Tags: envoyproxy, kuma

Hi I'm trying to debug a service w/an envoy problem deployed in kuma service mesh.  The service in question uses the default `kuma.io/sidecar-injection: enabled` annotation to inject the kuma sidecar and enable the envoy proxy.

One blocker to debugging is the service is being hit every few seconds with readiness checks(this complicates things because the additional requests trigger breakpoints out of band of my current request I'm trying to debug).

I've attempted to disable them at the kuma level with:

```
 KUMA_RUNTIME_KUBERNETES_VIRTUAL_PROBES_ENABLED:            false
```

env var set on the kuma-control-plane

No luck.  Additionally I've also tried defining a health check for the app that just pings every 5 minutes or so, but that also didn't seem to change the behavior of the existing readiness check.

EDIT:
Looks like this readiness healthcheck is defined on the injected kuma-sidecar

```
    Readiness:  http-get http://:9901/ready delay=1s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=12
```

But I'm still unsure of how to go about override a sidecar readiness check?

Much appreciation for any suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to remove the probes from your k8s deployment manifest. Kuma only rewrites existing probes.